# From mapStateToProps to setState

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is it possible to set the properties from mapStateToProps and use setState to change the state and save that information to my database? The data is being returned from google books api and I want to save a small portion of the data.

My state:

```
state = {
    title: '',
    subtitle: '',
    authors: '',
    description: '',
    thumbnail: '',
    buyLink: ''
};
```

Function to setState and save to database

```
let { book } = this.props.book;

    let bookInfo;

    if (book !== null) {
        const onSave = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        let savedData = this.setState({
                title: book.volumeInfo.title,
                subtitle: book.volumeInfo.subtitle,
                authors: book.volumeInfo.authors,
                description: book.volumeInfo.description,
                thumbnail: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
                buyLink: book.saleInfo.buyLink
            });
            console.log(savedData);
        };
        // this.props.saveBook(savedData, this.props.history);
        bookInfo = <BookInfo book={book} onClick={onSave} />;
    }
```

savedData returns undefined

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  book: state.books
 });
```

Comment: Because `this.setState()` doesn't return anything. Whatever you want to take from it - you won't, because setState() won't give it to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to `save` something to a database, you don't need to call `setState()` at all. State and Props are just mechanisms used by React to manage data and interactions with the data (this is an overly gross simplification).

looking at your code, you just need to convert your `book` object to a smaller/different format.

```
saveData = () => {
    // The code below just shows intention and shouldn't be used as is.
    let book = this.props.book
    let bookToSave = {
            title: book.volumeInfo.title,
            subtitle: book.volumeInfo.subtitle,
            authors: book.volumeInfo.authors,
            description: book.volumeInfo.description,
            thumbnail: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
            buyLink: book.saleInfo.buyLink
        }
    this.props.save(bookToSave, this.props.history);
}
render() {
    <BookInfo book={this.props.book} onSave={this.saveData} />
}
```

My understanding of your flow seems to be:

1. you call an API which gives you a lot of data
2. you show this data on the screen
3. you allow a user to save it

Based on the above, I do not see any need for you to copy the book into a state.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to log savedData you need to use the setState callback like this :

```
 this.setState({
                title: book.volumeInfo.title,
                subtitle: book.volumeInfo.subtitle,
                authors: book.volumeInfo.authors,
                description: book.volumeInfo.description,
                thumbnail: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
                buyLink: book.saleInfo.buyLink
            }, ()=>{
                  console.log(this.state)
                 this.props.saveBook(this.state, this.props.history);
               });
```